# como puedo validar usuarios y contraseñas antes de mandar los datos. desde ya muchas gracias

Tags: php, javascript, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <div class="modal-content">

    <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <div class="modal-header" style="background: #dd4b39; color: white">

    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Usuario</h4>        
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="box-body">

      <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-user"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
        name="nuevoNombre" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ENTRADA DIRRECCION -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-address-book"> 
        </i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
        name="nuevaDireccion" placeholder="Direccion" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ENTRADA TELEFONO -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-phone-square"> 
            </i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
           name="nuevoTelefono" placeholder="Telefono" required>
        </div>
      </div>

       <!-- ENTRADA OBSERVACION -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-info-circle"></i> 
          </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
           name="nuevaObservacion" placeholder="Observacion" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL USUARIO -->

      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-key"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" 
          name="nuevoUsuario" placeholder="Ingresar Usuario" required>
        </div>
      </div>

       <!-- ENTRADA PARA CONTRASEÑA -->


      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-lock"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" 
      name="nuevoPassword" minlength="4" maxlength="10" 
     placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña (Minimo 4 caracteres)" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- REPETIR CONTRASEÑA -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-lock"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" 
     name="repetirPassword" minlength="4" maxlength="10" 
         placeholder="Repetir Contraseña (Minimo 4 caracteres)" required>
        </div>
      </div>


       <!-- ENTRADA PARA SELECCIONAR SU PERFIL -->
      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="input-group">

          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class=" fa fa-users"></i> 
         </span>
         <select class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPerfil">

           <option value="">Seleccionar perfil</option>

           <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>

            <option value="Especial">Especial</option>

            <option value="Vendedor">Vendedor</option>

            <option value="Proveedor">Proveedor</option>

            <option value="Cliente">Cliente</option>
         </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="panel">SUBIR FOTO</div>
        <input type="file" id="nuevaFoto" name="nuevaFoto">
        <p class="help-block"> Peso máximo de la foto 200MB</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data- 
    dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar usuario</button>
   </div>

  <?php

    $crearUsuario= new ControladorUsuarios();
    $crearUsuario-> ctrCrearUsuario();


  ?>


   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 --------
<?php

  class ControladorUsuarios{
 /*Ingreso de usuarios*/

 static public function ctrIngresoUsuario(){

    if(isset($_POST["ingUsuario"])){
        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingUsuario"]) && 
   preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["ingPassword"])){

            $tabla="usuarios";
            $item="usuario";
            $valor=$_POST["ingUsuario"];
            $respuesta=ModeloUsuarios::MdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, 
   $valor);

            if($respuesta["usuario"] == $_POST["ingUsuario"] && 
   $respuesta["password"] == $_POST["ingPassword"]){

                $_SESSION["iniciarSesion"]= "ok";

                echo '<script>

                window.location="inicio";

                </script>';



            }else{

                echo'<br><div class="alert alert-danger"> El Usuario o la 
        Contraseña no son validos</div>';
            }

        }
    }
}

/*Registro de usuario*/

 static public function ctrCrearUsuario()
{
    if(isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', 
      $_POST["nuevoNombre"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["repetirPassword"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', 
      $_POST["nuevaDireccion"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoTelefono"]) 
        && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', 
     $_POST["nuevaObservacion"]))
        {





        }
        else
        {

            echo '<script>

                swal({
                    type: "error",
                    title: "¡Ningun campo puede ir vacio o llevar caracteres 
                   especiales!",
                    showConfirmButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                    closeOnConfirm: false

                    }).then((result)=>{

                        if(result.value){

                            window.location="usuarios";
                        }



                        });
                </script>';
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hola,  esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [editar](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés leer [ask]. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Existen dos tipos de validaciones:

- Las que se realizan **desde el lado del cliente**: Son útiles para *detectar los errores del formulario* de forma rápida sin necesidad de esperar a la comprobación del lado del servidor. Por contra, estas no son seguras y las normas de la validación pueden ser alteradas fácilmente.
- Las que se realizan del **lado del servidor**: Son necesarias porque se trata de la validación que hace el propio servidor cuando recibe los datos, en un proceso donde no puede intervenir el cliente.

Cuando se hace cualquier formulario, es muy recomendable usar los dos tipos:

#### Del lado del cliente:

1. **TYPE**: Es un atributo que se coloca a los input para indicar el tipo de dato. Si necesitas que sea un email, puedes introducir type="email".
2. **MINLENGTH**: Indica el número mínimo de caracteres a introducir con minlength="8".
3. **MAXLENGTH**: Indica el número máximo de caracteres a introducir con maxlength="32".
4. **REQUIRED**: Haz que los campos imprescindibles deban ser rellenados obligatoriamente con required.
5. **MAX** y **MIN**: Si el campo es numérico, puedes usar min="1" y max="10" para indicar que por ejemplo, el valor mínimo es de 1 y el máximo es de 10.
6. **Más**: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

**JavaScript**: Puedes usar JavaScript para hacer otras verificaciones también al lado del servidor, como por ejemplo, verificar si las contraseñas son iguales:

```
function validarFormulario() {
  if (document.getElementById('nuevoPassword').value != 
      document.getElementById('repetirPassword').value) {

      alert('Las contraseñas no coinciden');
      return false;
  }
}
```

> **¡No te olvides!** Añade: `onsubmit="return validarFormulario()"` al botón para
>   que haga la revisión.

#### Del lado del servidor:

Lo más común es usar PHP, y con este puedes hacer todo tipo de validaciones:

- Longitud mínima y máxima: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strlen.asp
- Validar email: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp
- Otras validaciones: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

> No me he extendido demasiado en la validación del lado del servidor a
>   pesar de ser la más importante porque solo se está preguntando por la
>   primera.

Comment: Solo quiero comparar las dos contraseñas para corroborar que son iguales. Pero si tenés que enviar los datos ni refrescar la pag

Comment: Deberías haber dicho eso en la pregunta, pero no hay problema, ahora te muestro como (edito la respuesta).

Comment: @Gabriel Ya está.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: @Gabriel De nada. Recuerda que para que StackOverflow sea mejor, hay que aceptar las respuestas que sirven al usuario. Saludos.